# Image 100% of a div

Tags: javascript, css, image, resize

How can I make an image 100% of a div ?

I have a 300x300 image and I want to make it the full size of a bigger div. (the size of this div can change, so I have to specify somewhere 100% of it)

Is there a solution in CSS or Javascript ?

Comment: or background: url('link') center top  no-repeat;
that will fit the div.

Comment: I want not to background it. But the answer below is the solution. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<img src="test.jpg" alt="test" id="bg" />

img#bg {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

css3 also supports this:

```
 #testbg{
background: url(bgimage.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Wow... I was sure I've already tried this. Well, it is perfectly working. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the CSS style `width: 100%` in the image tag to have it cover the whole space of its parent container.

Example or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNk7S/):

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
  <img src="yourPic.png" style="width: 100%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> `<div style="width:450px;height:450px;">`
>           `<img src="photo.png" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>`
>   `</div>`

Answer (score 1):

The CSS below will **scale** your image and fill 100% of the width of your div

```
#imgId {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

However if you actually want to fill the entire div by stretching the image use

```
#imgId {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

One other useful tip is when your width is specified as a percentage and your image is square, as yours is.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="sample.jpg">
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
​.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    // % padding is calculated as % of width rather than height 
    // so height will equal 50%
    padding-bottom: 50%; 
}

img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    // image is square so as long as width is 100% then height will be the same.
    height: auto;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The above means the image will always resize to fit the parent div exactly.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/JqJZ4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/XUZV5/

```
<div style="height:100px;width:300px;">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/Mars-Schiaparelli.jpg/280px-Mars-Schiaparelli.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100px;"/>
</div>​
```